# How do I get rid of an annoying (repeating) download pop-up in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, downloads

I downloaded VB0x Extension pack and installed it last week and it works like a dream.  My problem is every-time I open Firefox v11 the download prompt opens asking me to download the VB extension pack again.  How do I get rid of it?

Comment: Maybe you just have the link opened in one of your tabs?

Comment: No, I looked at that possibility, as well as checking Sync and other add-ons a possible causes.  Its nothing obvious

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like firefox uses the download URL as home page. So, check your firefox preferences, especially the home page. You can reset the home page easily:

[image: Reset Homepage in Firefox]

(Screenshot from [Mozilla Knowledge Base](http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/How%20to%20set%20the%20home%20page))

Comment: No Firefox was not using the download URL as homepage.  Home Page was pointing at Google search engine, but thanks to you the problem is now resolved.  I unchecked the "Show the Downloads window" and restarted Firefox. No more pop up.  It alway amazes how sometimes the simple things baffle us.

Comment: @StephenMyall: ah, ok, good to hear that the issue is solved anyway :-)